# python: cant scrape table data from html website

Tags: python, html, html-table, polygon, screen-scraping

I have tried for hours to get the "decoded input data" from: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x0d2e262cd328f53977d166a5cd1df3a9510b533efc81c71faa626b75cb7826e0
(to find it scroll down and click "see more" and then "decode input data"

I scraped a lot of information from etherscan before but could never get the decoded input data table. (Also tried getting it via the web3 module + the polygonscan API but the contract isnt open-source/ verified to it doesnt seem to work.)

```
    from requests_html import HTML
    html = HTML(html=htmldata)
    #print(html.text) #this works, prints the entire html text
    

    inputdatafind = html.find('#decodebox') #tried 50 variations of this like:
    inputdatafind = html.find('table.table.table-sm.table-hover')
    inputdatafind = html.find('div.table.table-sm.table-hover')
```

not sure what else to include, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use xpath to get the data you need. something like:

````
  1 import requests
  2 from lxml import etree
  3 
  4 s = requests.session()
  5 r = s.get("https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x0d2e262cd328f53977d166a5cd1df3a9510b533efc81c71faa626b75cb7826e0")
  6 tree = etree.HTML(r.content)
  7 inputdata = tree.xpath('//textarea[@id="inputdata"]/text()')
  8 
  9 print(inputdata)```
````